# Does assigning a property of a tuple contained in a Swift Dictionary change the Dictionary itself?

Tags: ios, swift, dictionary, thread-safety

Given is a Swift Dictionary which maps an Int to a tuple. For instance:

```
var tuples: [Int: (Int, Int)] = [1: (1, 1), 2: (2, 2), 3: (3, 3)]
```

Does assigning one element of one tuple mutate internal state of the Dictionary?

```
tuples[1].0 = 8 // Was the dictionary itself changed now?
```

Further, is concurrent access on different tuples in the Dictionary thread-safe? What about concurrent access to the same tuple, but different elements of the tuple?

```
// Is this safe? 
dispatch_async(queue1) {
    tuples[1].0 = 10
}
dispatch_async(queue2) {
    tuples[1].1 = 10
}


// What about this? 
dispatch_async(queue1) {
    tuples[1].0 = 10
}
dispatch_async(queue2) {
    tuples[2].1 = 10
}
```

Do other Swift collections (for example Array) behave the same way? What would happen if we would use a Dictionary mapping to some object type instead of a tuple?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that does change the Dictionary. Value types that are contained in another aggregate are "part of" that aggregate, rather than a separate entity. So this applies to a tuple inside a Dictionary, an Array inside a Dictionary, etc...

Given that, no, that's not thread-safe. In practice it *probably* is safe as long as the Dictionary is uniquely referenced (non-uniquely referenced Dictionaries will copy their backing store when it mutates), but that's difficult-to-impossible to guarantee.

If you wrap the tuple in an object, that would be sufficient, as long as only one thread at a time acts on any given object.

Answer (score 1):

Just a little example so you can see the dictionary does get changed:

```
var test = [1: (1, 1), 2: (2, 2), 3: (3, 3)] { didSet { print("dictionary changed") } }
test[1]?.0 = 3

// Dictionary changed
```

Comment: I tried that myself too. :)
My train of thought was that it's possible to implement such callbacks without modifying some internal dictionary state.

Comment: Well, like Catfish_Man said, wrapping the tuple in an object will do just that :)